# Mapping named parameters to indices for PreparedStatement as DSL - follow-up

Tags: kotlin, sqlite, jdbc, dsl

In the [previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/286786/mapping-named-parameters-to-indices-for-preparedstatement) I showed you my first attempt to handle named SQL parameters with JDBC and you were right, it wasn't as intuitive as I thought. The `ParameterMap` requires there an aditional variable to store it and has an unrelated property `sqlWithQuestionMarks` that holds the JDBC compatible string.

Since we're talking Kotlin here, what was missing most in the first version? Exactly, **lambdas**! Now they're the most important part of the new simple DSL for SQL parameters.

I'll start with an **example**:

```
private val selectQuery = File("sql/select_person.sql").readText()
private val selectStatement = sqliteConnection.prepareStatementFor<Filter>(selectQuery) {
    setParameter("first_name", preparedStatement::setString) { firstName }
    setParameter("last_name", preparedStatement::setString) { lastName }
}
```

That's it! Initialize each parameter and you're good to go.

Later in another function you call `setParameters` on it and do what you need to do:

```
    override fun select(filter: Filter): Sequence<Person> = sequence {
        selectStatement
            .setParameters(filter)
            .executeQuery()
            .use { result ->
                while (result.next()) {
                    yield(Person().apply {
                        firstName = result.getString("first_name")
                        lastName = result.getString("last_name")
                    })
                }
            }
    }
```

where `Filter` is an `interface` in this case (just for reference):

```
    interface Filter {
        val firstName: String?
        val timeframe: String?
    }
```

#### DSL

You start with `prepareStatementFor` that takes care of parsing the SQL, replacing named placeholders with question marks, creating a `PrepartedStatement` and finally it gives you back an instance of `NamedStatement` as `this`.

```
fun <T> java.sql.Connection.prepareStatementFor(sql: String, block: NamedStatement<T>.() -> Unit): NamedStatement<T> {
    val parameterRegex = Regex(":(?<parameterName>[a-z0-9_]+)", RegexOption.IGNORE_CASE)
    val parameterIndices = mutableMapOf<String, List<Int>>()
    var parameterIndex = 1 // <-- JDBC starts counting with 1.
    val sqlWithQuestionMarks = parameterRegex.replace(sql) { match ->
        // Not finding a parameter is not an option, so I just assume it's definitely not null.
        match.groups["parameterName"]!!.value.lowercase().let {
            parameterIndices.computeIfPresent(it) { _, indices -> indices + parameterIndex++ }
            parameterIndices.computeIfAbsent(it) { listOf(parameterIndex++) }
        }
        return@replace "?"
    }

    return NamedStatement<T>(parameterIndices, prepareStatement(sqlWithQuestionMarks)).also(block)
}
```

The `NamedStatement` keeps track of each parameter in an `internal` list and lets you set them later via `setParameters` by passing an object holding their values.

```
class NamedStatement<T> internal constructor(
    val parameterIndices: Map<String, Iterable<Int>>,
    val preparedStatement: PreparedStatement
) : AutoCloseable {

    internal val parameters = mutableListOf<(T) -> Unit>()

    fun setParameters(item: T): PreparedStatement {
        preparedStatement.clearParameters()
        for (parameter in parameters) {
            parameter(item)
        }
        return preparedStatement
    }

    override fun close() {
        preparedStatement.close()
    }
}
```

The last part is the extension method for `NamedStatement` that lets you add each parameter:

```
fun <T, TParameter> NamedStatement<T>.setParameter(
    name: String,
    setter: (Int, TParameter) -> Unit,
    getter: T.() -> TParameter
) {
    parameters.add { item ->
        parameterIndices.getValue(name).forEach { index ->
            setter(index, getter(item))
        }
    }
}
```

---

It now hides all the ugly parts like maps and loops, but maintains its flexibility by letting you dynamically specify the function you need to use to set a parameter like `setString` or `setInt` etc. What do you think?

Comment: `firstName`, `lastName` and `preparedStatement` are not defined in the example. The code looks overcomplicated at first glance.

Comment: @QuasiStellar all three come from `this` passed via `block: NamedStatement<T>.() -> Unit` and `getter: T.() -> TParameter` like in the `apply`. That's what I love about Kotlin ;-]

Comment: I'm not following what the getter and setter is for. What is the function `preparedStatement::setString`? The getters seem like unnecessary overcomplication since they're evaluated immediately, one time. Why not just take a TParameter argument directly? Getter lambdas would be useful for actions that are evaluated either later, or a number of times that is not necessarily exactly once. Why is `setParameter` an extension function?

Comment: I would say it's poor encapsulation to take a mutable type as a constructor parameter and start mutating it. Passing of mutable instances around should generally be avoided when possible since allowing something to be mutated from multiple different classes at once leaves open the possibility for all kinds of bugs.

Comment: @Tenfour04: the getters are evaluated later and multiple times. They get the actual value of the passed parameter class (item) and are stored in a list as lambdas. The setter stores the function ref of the prepared statement method of the corresponding parameter type so that I don't have to provide them all myself. You get the value from item's property and send it to the prepared statement using its own set-method.

Comment: @Tenfour04: the constructor takes a mutable type, but it doesn't mutate it. The API only accesses its properties to fill in the parameters. The mutability is used elsewhere in the application. And if you mean the prepared statement then it's need to be mutated. This crap is a huge  bottleneck if you create it on every request. It's what the JDBC documentation recommends.